# Could we lock stateless session bean instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, istatelesssession

guys,

For some reason, I try to hit the max-size of stateless session bean pool.

I can use a mass of threads to do that, by looking up my stateless session bean "at the same time", but it requires to consume many loops or many threads to do that, because sometimes it picked created bean instance from pool. As a result, Max-size can't be reach.

So, my question is here: Can we find a way to lock the instance(not like doing massive math calculation task), keeping a "working" status and don't send back to free-pool, Then we may use the Thread[max-pool-size] to reach to goal, without doing some annoying loops.

Thanks,

Comment: locking it will defeat their purpose.

Comment: I agree, but I want to test the max-pool-size is reached without a massive loops+threads attack, any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to test that do it the proper way with a lot of threads etc. Because then only the actual bugs if any will be visible... Or just create a bean with a task that will take about 5 min and just grab the beans.... Either will work I think...